# How to authenticate user using Firebase RESTful API?

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-authentication

is it possible to authenticate user using a Firebase RESTFul APi (With out RealTime data stream)

Does Firebase has something like a endPoint where I can Post the User Credentials and expect the response to be user Object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are trying to do is already [fully documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth).  You will need the user's authentication token and pass it as part of the request as shown in the docs.

Comment: I have gone through this and I wonder how we can retrieve access token using RESTful ?

Comment: You need to be using Firebase Authentication to get that token for the user that's currently signed in.

Comment: Okay. That brings back to the same question, How do I authenticate user in order to signin using RESTful ?

Comment: Use the appropriate Firebase Authentication client SDK for the platform you're developing on.  It will manage the interactions with the server.  If you're writing a server app, use the Admin SDK.